# How to expect empty string in Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

There's a test, where I cannot check a call of mocked function with an argument of `""` (empty string), why?

```
jest.mock('process', () => ({
  stdout: {
    clearLine: jest.fn(),
    write: jest.fn(),
    cursorTo: jest.fn()
  }
}))
let process = require('process')
let spinnerFactory = require('../spinner')

let write = process.stdout.write

...

it('creates a spinner with text', () => {
    let spinner = spinnerFactory()
    expect(spinner).toBeDefined()
    spinner.start()
    expect(write).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(write).toHaveBeenCalledWith('')
})
```

I got this error:

```
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: ""
Received: ""

Number of calls: 1
```

Comment: [this works fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-test-forked-9hbxd?file=/index.test.js). It's likely you're making an assumption that isn't true

Comment: @vyenky - you must be using a piped stream which is empty. what you see on terminal is a string representation of an actual object.

Comment: please add the source code of `spinner` or at least parts of importing `process` and calling `write`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is the string is not actually empty, but contains a "zero-width space" character U+200B or another character like it. You can copy the received value into a text editor that supports printing white space to check.

See my example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-test-forked-q4n8uo?file=/index.test.js)